# What is the equivalent of the R command "source" in Stata?

Tags: r, stata

I am an R enthusiast struggling the land of Stata. I have encountered the following problem in my attempts to "translate" from R to Stata:

In R, so that my script files don't get too big and crazy I like to write them in smaller parts and then have one main R script that reads in the smaller ones e.g.

1. `source("script-1.R")`
2. code blah1
3. code blah2
4. `source("script-2.R")` etc......

I would like to do the same thing in Stata and have tried doing

1. `do "script-1.do"`
2. code blah1
3. code blah2
4. `do "script-2.do"` etc......

However, I find that if I create a macro in `script-1.do` e.g. `local bird 1` 
The object/macro bird is not accessible in the main script or accessible to `script-2.do`. If I try to display the contents of `bird` in the main script, it's just empty.

Why is this? Any advice?

Comment: May I suggest you reviewed answers that were provided to some of your past questions and see whether any can be checked as 'acceptable' answers. Don't forget you can also vote on the ones that were helpful: this is the best way to help future visitors identifying relevant responses to specific problems.

Answer (score 7):

Try using `include`.  You can read about the differences between `include` and `do` (or `run`) here:

> [. help include](http://stata.com/help.cgi?include)

Answer (score 6):

Stata macros fall into two groups: `local` and `global`. The `local` ones only exist in the process in which they were defined (which can be an interactive session, do-file, or a `program`). If you defined something in `script-1.do`, it will only exist there, and you would have to explicitly `return` it to be visible elsewhere. (Do-files cannot really do that though; you'd have to define a `program, rclass` to return values, and breaking the chunks of code into `program`s is a good practice.) Avoid `global` macros unless absolutely, unavoidably necessary.

R has some control over the scope of its objects, but it isn't nearly any good compared to Stata's control over the macros. The variables and the data set are still global in Stata, and you cannot have more than one data set at a time. One other thing you will be pleasantly surprised with Stata is parameter passing by reference, which saves a lot of memory as compared to R's passing by value. So different packages have different strengths, and it would be short-sighted to say that one is better than the other.

Having said that, Keith's suggestion to use `include` is right on spot. I just tried to explain the "why" part of your question. Also, if what you need to exchange between the programs is a number, you can store it in an explicitly named `scalar` that will be visible to all processes.